# How to convert MATLAB code segment to single line?

Tags: matlab, ide, code-formatting

I'm looking for a way to convert a multi-line code such as :

```
for i=1:10
    foo();
end
```

to this :

```
for i=1:10, foo(); end
```

Is there an easy way for to do this in MATLAB Editor? Preferrably reversable?

I think I accidentally hit a keyboard shortcut few days ago, and saw the magic happen, but I couldn't find which keys did I press :)

Thanks for any help !

P.S. I'm not sure if this question belongs to superuser, but I believe I can find a quick answer here, and it will be relevant to programming, so win-win !

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify that you want the _Matlab editor_ to do this for you

Comment: @LuisMendo I edited the question. Thanks. By the way, I would also accept a Notepad++ extension or macro. But I want to believe there is a MATLAB way for this.

Comment: It's easy to make such a ViM macro...

Answer (score 0):

It work if you write it this way:

```
for i=1:10, foo();, end
```

(note the comma after foo();)

but what you probably did was just hit the + or - just before the for, which expand of collapse the "for" code sequence.

If you go in the "view" tab, there is also buttons to expand of collapse that can be use to do the same.

Comment: Nope, I did it with the keyboard. And I think that the expand/collapse does not change the code itself.

Comment: The `,` after the `foo()`  is not necessary if there is already a `;` to terminate the statement (and suppress the console output at the same time). It's either or ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is no way for you to have done that in MATLAB, at least not with a keyboard shortcut in the MATLAB Editor. I don't like to say you're imagining it, but I think you're imagining it.

The closest thing I can guess you might have done is to fold the current section of code, using either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> to fold the current section or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> to fold all the sections in the current file. This might look a little bit like you saw, with the main loop block disappearing, replaced by `for i = 1:10` and a rectangle with three dots - when you hover on the rectangle, the loop body would appear as a tooltip.

If that does turn out to be what you did, then it is reversible with either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> (for the current section) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> (for all sections). By the way, those shortcuts are the defaults and are customisable in the Preferences, and to work you need to have turned on Code Folding in the Preferences.

But, as you mention in another comment, code folding doesn't change the code itself, just its appearance; so this doesn't really capture what you're describing exactly.

The only other keyboard shortcut that I can imagine being relevant is Smart Indent (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>). This does some smart indenting of code, but again not exactly what you're describing here.

Comment: Thanks, even though it's bad news :) I'm pretty sure I saw the code (including the part after 'for') but yes maybe I was imagining. Ok, let me wait for a few more days, maybe something will come up.